# Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift

In the following part of my code i get the issue

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSDictionary'

```
do {
    var json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
      if let parseJSON = json {
        var resultValue: String = parseJSON ("status") as String!
        print ("result:\(resultValue)")         
        if resultValue == "success" {
          // Login is successful
          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: ("isUserLoggedIn"))
          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
          self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
      }     
    } catch let error as NSError{
  print("error=\(error)")            
}
```

I already tried to place the if statement outside the do catch statement, but then i get the issue "Use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Comment: Use `[]` to access a dictionary element, not `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
String = parseJSON ("status")
```

is trying to call an array or (in this case) dictionary as a function. The syntax you're looking for uses `[]` instead of `()`:

```
String = parseJSON["status"]
```

You also shouldn't be using brackets in your user default code:

```
forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
```

if you're not careful with brackets you start to define tuples and run into other issues...

Comment: Apple could change the error message. For example "You are trying to use a dictionary as if it was a function".